# Error with python packaging: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'NeuralBasics'

Tags: python, pypi, python-packaging

I'm building and packaging a small python module, and I succesfully uploaded to pypi and downloaded it. However, when I try to import it once installed I get this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'NeuralBasics'

This is my file structure:

```
.
├── MANIFEST.in
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── setup.py
├── src
│   └── NeuralBasics
│       ├── example2.jpeg
│       ├── example.jpeg
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── network.py
│       ├── test.py
│       ├── trained_data.txt
│       ├── training
│       │   └── MNIST
│       │       ├── big
│       │       │   ├── train-images.idx3-ubyte
│       │       │   ├── train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
│       │       │   ├── train-labels.idx1-ubyte
│       │       │   └── train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
│       │       ├── info.txt
│       │       └── small
│       │           ├── t10k-images-idx3-ubyte
│       │           ├── t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
│       │           ├── t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte
│       │           └── t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
│       └── utils.py
└── tests
```

**This is the content in my setup.py file:**

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="NeuralBasics",
    version="1.0.5",
    packages=find_packages(include=['NeuralBasics', 'NeuralBasics.*']),
    description='Neural network basics module. Number detection on images.',
    author='Henry Cook',
    author_email='henryscookolaizola@gmail.com',
    install_requires=['numpy', 'alive_progress', 'Pillow', 'matplotlib', 'idx2numpy']
)
```

**Contents of my __init__.py file:**

```
from network import Network
from utils import process_image, process_mnist, interpret, show

__all__ = Network, process_image, process_mnist, interpret, show
```

This error occurs on multiple computers, and I'm sure it isn't an error with pypi. Thank you for your help in advance!